# git log -1 -p stash@{0} shows empty patch

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

To reprodoce this behaviour just init a new git repository, create a file, add and commit. Now edit this file again (no add, no commit this time) and stash. The result should look like this:

```
$ git log stash@{0} --graph --decorate
*   commit C (refs/stash)
|\  Merge: A C
| |     WIP on master: A init
| |
| * commit B
|/      index on master: A init
|
* commit A (HEAD, master)
      init
```

The diff between A and C shows the expected result:

```
$ git diff stash@{0}^..stash@{0}
diff --git a/file b/file
index b1b7161..51bdcb4 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
+a new uncommited change
init
```

I would expect the same output for the command

```
$ git log stash@{0}
```

but there is no patch. Why does this happen?
(This is not related to stashing: Same behaviour if you create the history using empty commit, no-ff, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because `git log -1 -p` doesn't show the diff for *any* commit with multiple parents. Additional options are needed for that. Normally, you might want to pick `git show` for showing one single commit along with the patch, which is mostly equivalent but adds `--cc` as a default option. Explicitly adding that gets you a diff with `git log` too.

There are other options for controlling the display of merge commits: you can use `-c` to get a more verbose form of `--cc`, `-m` to get a regular diff to all parents (A and B), or combine that with `--first-parent` to get a plain diff from A to C.

Comment: Maybe you got me wrong. I didn't add to the index before stash. So B contains the same version of the file as A. And the worktree changes before stash are within C. If you diff A..B you will get no changes. If you diff A..C the worktree change will be shown (same for B..C). While A is the first parent of C, i would assume git log -1 -p should Show the change?

Comment: @Henning It shouldn't, but you're right, I goofed, sorry for getting my own testing wrong. I rewrote my answer. (Normally totally rewriting answers like this is not accepted because it's unfair to misrepresent existing votes, but nobody voted on this answer yet.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! So wouldn't it be advisable to have git-log choose the same diff-options as git-show. Or are there objections?

Comment: @Henning From a user perspective I would probably agree with you. From the perspective of the Git developers, I don't know, I would only be able to make guesses there. It seems like a reasonable feature request.